# awk - formating of columns - problem with comma

Tags: awk

What is wrong with this awk command please? I would like to print the first column, tab, second column, tab, third column.

```
{printf "%.6f, %s, %.6f, %s, %.6f\n", $1+56000, "\t", $2/1000, "\t", $3/1000}
```

Now the result is:

```
58375.475955,   , -0.012080,    , 0.007051
58375.476190,   , -0.006480,    , 0.007051
```

The desired result:

```
58375.475955     -0.012080   0.007051
58375.476190     -0.006480   0.007051
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have more columns you don't want to keep adding them to `printf`, as an alternative you can set the default number format and set the output field separator and use `print`.

```
$ echo 23423.4353 234.23423 2342.23423 | 
  awk -v OFMT='%.6f' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1+56000, $2/1000, $3/1000}'

79423.435300    0.234234        2.342234
```